# How take html dash-case input tag name in js

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Case to naming all HTML parameters and now I have some troubles. I want take value from *form input* but JS don't taking dash-case. There is any way to take form input without changing *input name*?

HTML and JavaScript:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#message-form');
console.log(form.user-message.value); //Here rise error
```

```html
<form id="message-form">
    <input type="text" name="user-message">
</form>
```

Comment: Also if you have better idea to post title you can write it bellow (my english is still not good enough :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it like this:

```js
form['user-message'].value
```

Answer (score 1):

Change name to `usermessage` and it will work

```
<form id="message-form">
    <input type="text" name="usermessage">
</form>


const form = document.querySelector('#message-form');
console.log(form.usermessage.value)
```

Or add querySelector for message

```
var message = form.querySelector('input[name="user-message"]').value;
```

Comment: I marked i don't want change input name. But thanks :>